# How can I use a new line, in my editor, without throwing off indentation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When typing a long line, such as a paragraph, or a img src, I would like to hit return so that my text does not run off the screen. When I start a new line however this throws off my indentations.

Is there a way to work with long lines of code, without messing up bootstraps indentation syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for an editor-function called "word-wrap". At least thats what it is called in sublime text 3.

To set it up in sublime. Go to "view" -> "word wrap". This will force a new line if the text becomes to long, but it also keeps (and moves) the code onto the next line.

You could also manually wrap into a new line. For example:

From this:

```
<p>
<img class="some class names in here" id="my-ultra-nice-image-from-the-last-century" src="https://www.example.com/incrediblylongurlnameloremipsumdolorsitloremipsumdolorsitloremipsumdolorsit/lorem/134124234.jpg" alt="" />
</p>
```

To that:

```
<p>
<img class="some class names in here" 
     id="my-ultra-nice-image-from-the-last-century"  
     src="https://www.example.com/incrediblylongurlnameloremipsumdolorsitloremipsumdolorsitloremipsumdolorsit/lorem/134124234.jpg" 
     alt="" />
</p>
```

But you cannot do something like this. This would result in invalid html.

```
<p>
<img class="some class names in here" 
     id="my-ultra-nice-image-from-the-last-century"  
     src="https://www.example.com/incrediblylongurl
     nameloremipsumdolorsitloremipsumdolorsitloremipsumdolorsit/lorem/134124234.jpg" alt="" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem with your editor, make sure to set the indentation value like 2 or 4.

Comment: The problem is that when a line is too long in my ediotr, it runs of the screen. I'd like to start a new line to prevent this, but then bootstrap thinks I'm no longer working with the same element(P, img, etc)

I want bootstrap to know I'm still editing the same element.

Comment: Use `  hope this would help you